# Fix orphaned user on migrated database

Tags: sql-server

I try to execute the following sentence on my migrated database, but it won't work:

`EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'username'`

> The user or the role 'username' does not exist in the database.

I assumed that this is because orphaned user, so I try the following to check it:

`EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'`

> Username 0x6D086A039CA9ED43AC16725C64EC3102

So, I have orphaned user and when I try to fix it the following error shows up:

`sp_change_users_login 'auto_fix', 'username'`

> The 'username' user row will be corrected when you update your login link with an existing one.
>   Msg 15331, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_change_users_login, Line 288 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   The 'username' user cannot perform the auto_fix action because the SID is duplicated.
>   The number of orphan users corrected when updating users is 0.
>   The number of orphan users corrected by adding new logins and updating users is 0.

How can I fix this error?

> The 'username' user cannot perform the auto_fix action because the SID is duplicated.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `sp_addrolemember` and `sp_change_users_login` anymore, both are deprecated and have been replaced with `ALTER ROLE` and `ALTER USER`/`ALTER LOGIN`.

Comment: @Larnu So, how I can fix orphaned user with ALTER USER / ALTER LOGIN?

Comment: You need to fix the duplicates first. They won't work either as it stnds.

Comment: A `sid` code is assigned to each user and login, try searching for duplicates first on the `syslogins` and `sysusers` views.